# FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using pdf package for my flutter app. It works on android and ios but it throws the following error when I try to generate pdf on windows.

error snap

[image]

**This is the code that generate pdf**

**pdf_api.file**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';

class PdfApi {
  static Future<File> saveDocument({
    required String name,
    required Document pdf,
  }) async {
    final bytes = await pdf.save();

    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${dir.path}/$name');

    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

    return file;
  }

  static Future openFile(File file) async {
    final url = file.path;

    await OpenFile.open(url);
  }
}
```

**pdf_invoice_api.dart file**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';
import 'package:saltanat_marriage_hall/api/pdf_api.dart';

import '../models/invoice.dart';
import '../utils.dart';

class PdfInvoiceApi {
  static Future<File> generate(Invoice invoice) async {
    final pdf = Document();
    print('pdf ${pdf.document}');
    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
      build: (context) => [
        buildHeader(invoice),
        SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
        buildTitle(invoice),
        buildInvoice(invoice),
        Divider(),
        buildTotal(invoice),
      ],
      footer: (context) => buildFooter(invoice),
    ));

    return PdfApi.saveDocument(
        name: 'sultanat_invoice${DateTime.now().toString()}.pdf', pdf: pdf);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the extension

```dart
final file = File('${dir.path}/$name.pdf');
```

Also remove spaces from filename.

Comment: I am passing the name with .pdf extension through arguments.

Comment: Check if the folder is read protected by antivirus or your system default settings

Comment: I have checked but there is no protection. I have already turned every protection off.

Comment: Not sure. Can you try without a space in filename?

Comment: wow! it worked I just changed the file name. thankyou.!

Comment: Edited mt answer to remove spaces in filename too. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.. glad it worked well

Comment: actually I am using the DateTime.now().toString() which causes the error I removed that  and it worked.

Comment: Cool. you can also do `fileName.replaceAll(" ","")` which will remove all spaces from the string